# Script to test for swap then exit gracefully

Tags: linux, bash

I am looking for a script that tests for swap and exits gracefully if swap is found as part of this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script formats and mounts /dev/sdc

{
if [ ! -f /scripts/alert ]; then
    echo "File not found!"
    exit 0
fi
} 

mkswap /dev/sdc && swapon /dev/sdc

#END
```

Comment: "cat /proc/swaps" should help you

Comment: I thought of that, but I doubt that would work in a if else statement

Answer (score 3):

Lacking a `swapinfo` (*BSD) ,`swapon -s` (swap usage) is the next best thing.

Any of the following should do the trick, setting `$?` to 0 if one or more swaps are set up:

```
/sbin/swapon -s | grep -q /dev
grep -q /dev /proc/swaps
free | awk '/Swap/{ exit(!$2)}'
awk '/SwapTotal/ {exit (!$2)}' /proc/meminfo
```

The last two commands are probably the most robust, the first two won't (as is) confirm the existence of swap when *only* swap files are used (somewhat unusual, but possibly found during an OS installation, or on diskless systems which [swap over NFS](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.6#head-90a9988ae90f3481e4e6ddcae356bb8c614b531e)).

You can use this instead to detect (or count, use `-c` instead of `-q`) swaps:

```
grep -qE "(partition|file)" /proc/swaps
```

(This will also count swap on `/dev/nbd` [network block devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_block_device), swap block devices are counted as "partition" swap devices, at least up until linux-3.13.5.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if every swap on every system always contains "/dev"... And/or if you wanted to know how many swaps are in use...

I think /proc/swaps should have an extra line for each swap that's in use, and if there's no swap then it's only one line (of titles).  So `wc -l` should tell the number of lines and therefore the number of swaps - 1.

So this should give the number of swaps in use:

```
 swapnum=$(( $(cat /proc/swaps|wc -l) - 1 ))
```

(or if you really hate cat for some reason,)

```
 swapnum=$(( $(wc -l < /proc/swaps) - 1 ))
```

and can be tested if = 0 or whatnot